# How to properly get user list from reactions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently trying to create a Discord Bot that randomizes people into 2 teams.
Right now I was able to send the messages with the reactions, and then returning a list of users that reacted to the bot's message. But I'm facing the following problems:

1. The list includes the bot;
2. The list only includes the bot and the first person that reacted to the message (I would like to randomize as soon as I hit 10 players not including the bot)
3. I need to separate the list into two teams

```py
if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅': ## right now this is just selecting the game
    def check(reaction, user): ## this check is here but I was unable to properly use it without breaking the code, or even defining the limit of 10 reactions
        return user != bot.user and (str(reaction.emoji) == '')

    msg_players1 = await ctx.send('Summoners, react below: ')
    await msg_players1.add_reaction('')
    msg_players1 = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg_players1.id)
    reactions = msg_players1.reactions
    users = set()
    
    for reactions in user, reaction:
        async for user in reaction.users():
            users.add(user)

    await ctx.send(f"time 1: {', '.join(user.name for user in users)}")
```

I'm very new to coding, even more to Discord bots, any help is very much appreciated!
Thanks!

EDIT: I just tested and it's not returning the name of the user that is reacting to the  emoji, it's returning the name of the user that called the command

Comment: You can try to use a `while True` loop and wait for your reactions. To exclude a bot reaction we can check if the reaction comes from a user or not, also with a kind of loop. (Something like: `while user == self.bot.user`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fetching the message as soon as you add a reaction to it, there's not enough time for users to react to it. You could sleep `x` amount of seconds and fetch the message, but it's a really bad idea, you'd have to guess how much time to give for the 10 users to react.

Instead you can use a while loop, wait for the exact 10 reactions (excluding the bots) and continue.

```py
users = set() 

def check(reaction, user):
    return str(reaction) == "✅" and user != bot.user  # or `client.user`, however you named it

while len(users) < 10:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
    users.add(user)

# once here, divide the `users` set into teams
```

#### References:

- [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: Thank you very much, I made it work with a variation of this and converting the set to list via `players = list(users)` and then shuffling.